# How to detect Active Directory user on ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I have a web application which is largely a content system - that is, it displays help for another system.  It doesn't matter who views it.  However, there is a list of users I would like to display, and also provide a way to edit the list.  On that one page I want to detect the user's Active Directory information, and if the user is in the list of users authorized to change the data, then display an edit icon button to provide a means of editing some element.  I do not need nor want Windows Authentication determining whether the user can get to the page, only to discobver the user's logon creds.

In short, I want this:

```
// Get the user's creds
// Is user a page editor?
if (IsPageEditor(UserCreds))
{
    // put icon buttons for editing 
}
else
{
    // don't put icon button there
}
```

First of course is, getting the user credentials.  I should add that this will all be on a private company intranet, and every user will be signed into the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not need nor want Windows Authentication determining whether the user can get to the page, only to discobver the user's logon creds.

Why not?  Windows Authentication is the obvious, secure way to discover the Windows identity of the connected user.

Any other mechanism is insecure, i.e. a user who is not authorized to edit could spoof an authorized user's identity.  Using Windows Authentication doesn't preclude you from allowing any user to access the application.

> My understanding of setting Windows.Authentication ON is that it will challenge the user to give user name and password before allowing to view the page

No, this isn't correct.  If the server is in the same domain as the client, and the server is configured to allow all domain users to connect, there doesn't need to be a prompt to the end user.

> Our trouble ticket system "knows" who we are when we access the page -- it must be getting this information from Active Directory, from the current logged in user.

Probably it is using Windows authentication.  Try examining the HTTP flow between the browser and your trouble ticket system with a tool such as Fiddler: you'll probably see an authentication challenge/response.

Comment: Most of the site is concerned with content that anyone at all (within the intranet) may view.  I want to display the page in question to anyone, but discover whether that user is authorized to edit the page, without requiring them to validate their identity.  My understanding of setting Windows.Authentication ON is that it will challenge the user to give user name and password before allowing to view the page.  If that is correct, then I cannot use it.

Comment: It must be possible to get the user's validated identity without requiring challenge/response.  Our trouble ticket system "knows" who we are when we access the page -- it must be getting this information from Active Directory, from the current logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

To get the current logged in user you need to call `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();`

From there you can do a lot of things depending on your requirement, get users groups, get OU information etc.  For a full AD wrapper I have a full article here

http://macaalay.com/2010/06/28/active-directory-c/

Comment: Excellent!  Just what I needed!

Comment: "To get the current logged in user you need to call WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();" - this generally returns the identity under which the Application Pool is running.

Comment: @Joe's comment here turns out to be correct, meaning I can't use WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() to silently identify the user in this situation.  Darn.